# WordPress directory path issues in js file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am unable  to give proper  path of root directory link, error is showing "http://localhost/wordpress/alerts.php 404 (Not Found) " alerts.php file theme folder main directory .

```
 .directive('alertsCenter', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'alerts.php',
          replace:true,
          restrict: 'E',
          controller:'alertsCtrl'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Use `get_template_directory()` function if you added file inside active theme folder

```
function print_my_inline_script() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'some-script-handle', 'done' ) ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//PASTE YOUR ALL JAVASCRIPT CODE
.directive('alertsCenter', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: '<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/alerts.php',
          replace:true,
          restrict: 'E',
          controller:'alertsCtrl'
        };
    });
</script>
<?php
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_script' );
```

Comment: please check what comes in templateUrl ..@SanjayYadav

Comment: it's just print the  get_template_url() and other thing

Comment: where did you add your file alerts.php ? @SanjayYadav

Comment: '<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/alerts.php'  and alerts .php file in theme main directory with header.php and function.php

Comment: I am not getting you , but i just replace your code with my code ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114019/discussion-between-vrajesh-and-sanjay-yadav). @SanjayYadav